# Is this set of functions linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\{\ln(x), \ln(x+1), \ln((x+1)^2)\}$$

I am almost positive it is linearly dependent. My real question is if my answer is a sufficient way to prove it. I rewrote the last function as $2\ln(x+1)$, which is a scalar multiple of the second function. Does that mean the set is linearly dependent?

Comment: How would you characterise being linearly dependent?

Comment: c1(first function) + c2(second function) + c3(third function) = 0 where c1 c2 and/or c3 are not equal to 0

Comment: $f_1,..., f_n$ are linearly dependent **iff** there are $c_k$, **not all zero** such that $c_1 f_1+c_2 f_2 + ... + c_n f_n= 0$.

Comment: Right, and if you plug in -2 for c2 and 1 for c3, that is an instance of that case, meaning it's linearly dependent?

Comment: Yes. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does mean they're linearly dependent because:

$$0\times\ln(x)-2\times \ln(x+1)+1\times \ln(x+1)^2=0$$

but $(0,-2,1)$ isn't zero

Comment: Ohhhh so for those c's, the sum of the functions is equal to 0, but because this is a nontrivial solution that means the set of functions is linearly dependent?

Comment: @Chris Precisely